# NullPointerException when calling a method of a class containing a set<> field

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

First off, I must say I am very new to Java programming.
Here is my problem:

I have the following class:

```
public class NfcRfConfig {

boolean enabled;
Set<String> tech;

public NfcRfConfig() {
    Log.i(tag, "Contructor");
    enabled = false;
    tech = new HashSet<String>();
}

public void setTech(String techno) {
        tech.add(techno);
}
}
```

I am using it in my application, from a Fragment:

```
Map<String, NfcRfConfig> mNfcRfConfig = new HashMap<String, NfcRfConfig>();

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.d(tag, "onCreateView()");

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rf_config, container, false);

    mContext = getActivity();

    Log.d(tag, "onCreateView() - preparing mNfcRfConfig");
    //NfcRfConfig config = new NfcRfConfig();
    mNfcRfConfig.put(NfcAdapterStExtensions.MODE_READER, new NfcRfConfig());
    mNfcRfConfig.put(NfcAdapterStExtensions.MODE_CE, new NfcRfConfig());
    mNfcRfConfig.put(NfcAdapterStExtensions.MODE_P2P_POLL, new NfcRfConfig());
    mNfcRfConfig.put(NfcAdapterStExtensions.MODE_P2P_LISTEN, new NfcRfConfig());

}
```

Then I have a bunch of checkBox, and when one is clicked, I want to call the method setTech() of my NfcRfConfig class:

```
    case R.id.pollAReader:
        Log.d(tag, "onClick() - pollAReader");
        NfcRfConfig config1 = mNfcRfConfig.get(NfcAdapterStExtensions.MODE_READER);
        if(box.isChecked() == true)//adds tech to list
        {               
            //Disable other options
            config1.setTech(NfcAdapterStExtensions.TECH_A);
        }
        else // remove tech from list
        {

            config1.removeTech(NfcAdapterStExtensions.TECH_A);
        }

        mNfcRfConfig.put(NfcAdapterStExtensions.MODE_READER, config1);          
        break;
```

But here is what I have in the logcat:

```
D/STNFCINfo2 - RfConfig( 1619): onCreateView()                                                                         
D/STNFCINfo2 - RfConfig( 1619): onCreateView() - preparing mNfcRfConfig                                  
I/NfcRfConfig( 1619): Contructor                                                                         
I/NfcRfConfig( 1619): Contructor                                                                         
I/NfcRfConfig( 1619): Contructor                                                                         
I/NfcRfConfig( 1619): Contructor                                                                                                                             
D/STNFCINfo2 - RfConfig( 1619): onClick() - entry                                                        
D/STNFCINfo2 - RfConfig( 1619): onClick() - pollAReader                                                  
I/NfcRfConfig( 1619): setTech(TECH_A)                                                                    
D/AndroidRuntime( 1619): Shutting down VM                                                                
W/dalvikvm( 1619): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416bcb90)                 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                           
E/AndroidRuntime( 1619): Process: com.android.stnfcinfo2, PID: 1619                                      
E/AndroidRuntime( 1619): java.lang.NullPointerException                                                  
E/AndroidRuntime( 1619):    at com.st.android.nfc_extensions.NfcRfConfig.setTech(NfcRfConfig.java:31)     
E/AndroidRuntime( 1619):    at com.android.stnfcinfo2.FragmentRfConfig.onClick(FragmentRfConfig.java:140) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1619):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
```

Is the error obvious to you?

Comment: what is the line 140 of FragmentRfConfig?

Comment: And what is NfcAdapterStExtensions.TECH_A ?

Comment: It is     config1.setTech(NfcAdapterStExtensions.TECH_A);

Comment: your setTech is throwing the exception, problably because you are passing it a null argument, instead of a valid string as you should, so again, what is NfcAdapterStExtensions.TECH_A ?

Comment: public static final String TECH_A = "TECH_A";

Comment: have you verified that `TECH_A` is correctly passed to `setTech()`

Comment: Yes I added a log (which is not in the code I posted). It is from this that I get the I/NfcRfConfig( 1289): setTech(TECH_A) log. I also tried using directly setTech("TECH_A") but I stil get the issue.

Comment: Can you post you removeTech method?

Comment: public void removeTech(String techno) {
  Log.i(tag, "removeTech(" + techno + ")");
  tech.remove(techno);
 }

Comment: I've tried to recreate a sample of your code (in plain java), and I get no errors, is it possible that you're using config1.setTech(NfcAdapterStExtensions.TECH_A); somewhere else in your code?

Comment: No there is only this one. The class NfcRfConfig I am using is part of an SDK addon that I load on my device (system/framework). Could the problem come from there?

Comment: Can't confirm, my advice to you is to use the debugger, and confirm the state and value of your variables step by step.

Comment: Whats the purpose of 
        mNfcRfConfig.put(NfcAdapterStExtensions.MODE_READER, config1);   ?